# Graphs all of whose cuts are positive

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

Let $(V, E, w)$ a weighted graph, with vertices $V$, edges $E$, and **signed weight** $w:E\to \mathbb R$.

I am interested to know other popular properties that are known to imply, or are equivalent to, the requirement that **all cuts of the graph are positive**. This part in boldface means that every time $V$ is partitioned in two nonempty sets $V=V_1 \cup V_2$, the sum of $w$ over the edges with one end in $V_1$ and the other in $V_2$, needs to be $>0$.

And by any chance, does this property have a fancy name?

Comment: This is almost obvious, but a necessary condition is that the sum of all the edge weights must be positive (since the sum of weights incident to every vertex must be positive).

Comment: true, but I think there must be something more general, an analogue of that for all cuts ?